# CoffeeScript: Can i pass parameters of a function while using async.parallel

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, async.js

I am stuck with a very naive problem. 
Can we pass parameters to function while passing the functions through a function array in async.parallels. 
Below is a template code. While calling fn1 and fn2 in parallel, i want to pass parameters to each of them.

```
fn1 = (param , callback) ->
  #somethg 
  # callback

fn2 = (param , callback) ->
  #somethg 
  # callback

async.parallel [fn1 , fn2 ] , (err, result) ->
   # results aggregated from fn1 and fn2
```

Comment: Sure. Can you provide an example of what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: please see the edits :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify additional arguments by wrapping the call to each `function` in another, passing along the `callback` provided by `async.parallel`:

```
arg = 'foo'

async.parallel [
  callback -> fn1 arg, callback,
  callback -> fn2 arg, callback
], (err, result) ->
  console.log result
```